# Access credential for http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/

Tags: itunes

I want to access EPF data from itunes. I got approved for the itunes' Affiliate Program. But when I tried to access http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/, it asks for a username and password. How can I get the login credentials for the URL? I read through https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html#overview but it doesn't describe how I can gain access. Many thanks!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I successfully went through this.

First of all I needed to create an Affiliate account, then I had to send support ticket from this account explicitely asking about EPF credentials, and then confirm that I really want EPF credentials (they warned be that it is very professional service blah blah blah) and then I got username/password I can pass to access their server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out already, but since other people are asking: the answer is right there at the top in the third paragraph:

> Access to the EPF requires login credentials and an active partnership with the affiliate program. Partners wishing to apply for access can do so by submitting a request at the [Affiliate Helpdesk](http://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/support) with the primary account holders contact info, proof of being active with the affiliate program and a short description explaining how they intend to use the EPF.

Comment: It is not helpful at all, in Apple you have: login, affiliate ID, unique user ID, API key and password and it is not clear which combination works properly.

Comment: I'm assuming that after approving you, the helpdesk will hand you a new set of credentials unique to that part of the site (and maybe a ftp server).

Comment: Indeed, I needed to issue a separate support ticket, from my affiliate account to get EPF credentials.

Comment: You can directly use the 'Submit a request' link in the top right; there is an Affiliate Token field, but it says it's optional. I tried walking in as a nobody, but they requested a working prototype of the website. Since they do not provide sample data for developers, nor the database schema, this created a chicken&egg problem. The prototype would have to use a completely made up, non-reusable backend.